# regexes in calendar

Tags: regex

I have a string in date format `06/09/2011 03:00 PM`. I want to remove all of the forward slashes, and if the first digit of the month (`06`) is a zero, remove it as well as the first digit of the day (`09`) remove it as well. Any body who can help me out?

thanks!

Comment: Any particular language your using ?

Comment: What string do you want to get out, assuming you use that sample string as your input? (Just edit this into your question.)

Comment: Can you give an example? Do you want the output to be `692011`?! What about `1112011`?

Comment: Good point to show up the ambiguity problem with this transformation.

Comment: sorry guys I didn't get back to you until now. I'm using javascript for this. I want to out put 692011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this is by taking an available date parser where you hand in the input format and output it to a different output format.

Patterns differ, Implementations etc differ also. It is not convenient neither practicable to do date parsing via regex.

Comment: _Parsing_, you can use REs for that. Anything beyond that (e.g., translating into epochal seconds or Julian days) is outside the scope.

Comment: You mean replacing e.g. SimpleDateFormat, DateParser in Java via a plain Regex and type transformations is more convenient ? That sounds simply wrong.

Comment: hey guys, so sorry for making such a weird question. I basically am doing a calendar app and I have dates swinging all over the place for different reasons. In this particular case I need to simply remove all of the 0's of the month and day within the string 06/09/2011... any clues? thanks

Comment: You take the format as output format which has no leading zeros for months and days

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```
0([1-9]+)/0([1-9]+)/([0-9]+)
```

Of course, it will only work in valid dates; it does not parse the date or anything.

---

BTW: I find better (more readable, detects errors in a more meaningful manner) fyr's answer. This is just to show that it can be done with regex, if fyr's solution is not available in your platform.